# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getTitleId' of undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, wordpress

I have been having problems with the simple-press plugin on my wordpress website. The developers of simple-press told me it has something to do with the website pulling jquery from google cdn. So we basically commented out all those

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_deregister_script('jquery-ui');
```

//commented them out in addition to the

```
wp_register_script('jquery'……
wp_register_script('jquery-ui…..
```

// and instead just have

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-widget');
```

I did thise to all the files on my website but i'm still getting the follow errors

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getTitleId' of undefined jquery.ui.dialog.min.js:5

a.widget._create jquery.ui.dialog.min.js:5

a.Widget._createWidget jquery.ui.widget.min.js:5

a.widget.a.(anonymous function).(anonymous function) jquery.ui.widget.min.js:5

a.widget.bridge.a.fn.(anonymous function) jquery.ui.widget.min.js:5

e.extend.each jquery.js:2

e.fn.e.each jquery.js:2

a.widget.bridge.a.fn.(anonymous function) jquery.ui.widget.min.js:5

spjPopupImage sp-forum.js:1
onclick /filamchw/message-discussion-board/news-announcements/another-topic-with-an-image/:389

Help anyone?? :( I am using salutation as my wordpress theme (go to themeforest to see a sample).

Thanks,
Greggy